# Introduction C-developer to TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm a C-developer and trying to learn TypeScript(without knowledge of JS\Node or etc. only C and some C++). And I'm trying to just read a few lines from stdin and can't do this... How to do this? And maybe someone knows a way how C-developer can learn TS\JS. Because now I can't understand how all of these modules and etc. works.

Bellow a code of how I was trying to read lines:

```js
import * as readline from 'readline';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

let p: Person = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };

rl.question('Enter your first name: ', (input) => {
    p.firstName = input;
});
rl.question('Enter your last name: ', (input) => {
    p.lastName = input;
});

rl.close();

console.log(`Hello ${p.firstName} ${p.lastName}!`);
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't do "this"?  How is the code in the question not working?  Are you getting an error?  What is the actual issue you're running into?

Comment: I'm compiling it via `tsc` and run via `node`, output: `Enter your first name: Hello  !` and its closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is an event-driven language which makes use of asynchronous callbacks to run code when IO becomes available. This is in contrast to the synchronous nature of many languages, like C and C++.

Your `rl.question` callbacks will not not call until after the input has been sent.

Your going to need to refactor you code to wait for those inputs. Here's one simple way you could do this.

```
import * as readline from 'readline';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

let p: Person = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };

rl.question('Enter your first name: ', (input) => {
    p.firstName = input;

    rl.question('Enter your last name: ', (input) => {
        p.lastName = input;

        rl.close();

        console.log(`Hello ${p.firstName} ${p.lastName}!`);
    });
});
```